# How do I connect to the remote SQL server from a python script in debian

Tags: python, sql-server, debian, remote-access, pymssql

I have a Windows computer that has an SQL Server installed on it. I also have another computer that has a virtual machine with Debian. In this virtual machine, there is a Python script that needs to connect to the SQL Server. That is, I need to connect remotely to the SQL Server on another computer.

In my SQL Server, I have created a user `remote_user` with a password and the necessary privileges. [image]

I have also enabled remote connections

[image]

enabled the TCP/IP protocol in the SQL Server configuration manager

[image]

checked the port for TCP/IP

[image]

launched the SQL Server browser and agent

[image]

and added port `1433` to the windows firewall allowed rules

[image]

I then try to connect to the server in my python script using the following code:

```
import pymssql
conn = pymssql.connect('ip_address', 'remote_user', 'password', 'db_name')
```

but receive an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "src/pymssql/_pymssql.pyx", line 646, in pymssql._pymssql.connect

  File "src/pymssql/_mssql.pyx", line 2126, in pymssql._mssql.connect

  File "src/pymssql/_mssql.pyx", line 716, in pymssql._mssql.MSSQLConnection.__init__

  File "src/pymssql/_mssql.pyx", line 1835, in pymssql._mssql.maybe_raise_MSSQLDatabaseException

  File "src/pymssql/_mssql.pyx", line 1852, in pymssql._mssql.raise_MSSQLDatabaseException

pymssql._mssql.MSSQLDatabaseException: (20009, b'DB-Lib error message 20009, severity 9:\nUnable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (ip_address)\nNet-Lib error during Connection timed out (110)\nDB-Lib error message 20009, severity 9:\nUnable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (ip_address)\nNet-Lib error during Connection timed out (110)\n')



During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:



Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

  File "src/pymssql/_pymssql.pyx", line 652, in pymssql._pymssql.connect

pymssql._pymssql.OperationalError: (20009, b'DB-Lib error message 20009, severity 9:\nUnable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (ip_address)\nNet-Lib error during Connection timed out (110)\nDB-Lib error message 20009, severity 9:\nUnable to connect: Adaptive Server is unavailable or does not exist (ip_address)\nNet-Lib error during Connection timed out (110)\n')
```

Did I miss something? What might cause such a problem?

Will appreciate any help!

Comment: FYI, sharing your public IP is an extremely foolish thing to do; especially when alongside a screenshot of the `LOGIN` name...

Comment: Likely your "Public IP address" is your router's public IP address, not the IP address of the computer running SQL Server.

Comment: If the host within the same network/domain as your SQL Server host? If so, your public IP isn't what you want; it's the IP of SQL Server's host. if they aren't in the same domain, and you're connecting over the WAN, you'll need to ensure you have port forwarding enabled and you limit that port to only be able to be access to the public IP of that external host (otherwise get ready for your SQL Server host to be brute forced attacked).

Comment: @Larnu Thank you! It is only a test database with nothing in it but I removed the IP address

Comment: Right now, they are in the same network, but I need it to work in two separate networks as well. What IP address should I use then?

Comment: What IP address you use will depend on your location, @OlegIvanytskyi .

Comment: But, for example, if they are on two different networks, the IP address would be the one I can find with googling "my IP address", correct?

Comment: Or, better to ask, where do I find the IP address of my SQL server?